Render Layer Mask Best Practise

I have an already rendered scene that I would like to put a fog overlay onto in compositing. The scene already has volumetrics, so I am compositing:

Env
Volmx
Main Scene
Fog overlay

The fog overlay works really well even though its slapped on top of everything, but I would like to get it better to fool the eye even more. What I'd like to do is take the objects selected in the screenshot and create a mask so that the Main Scene punches through the fog overlay.
I understand the principle, but I am wondering how best to do it. Also, I should be able to render it out quickly since I don't need their textures or any light information. So my questions:

Do I use a "View layer" or Linked Scene? Surely if I use a "View layer" then any alterations to the render settings will affect the main layer? Linked scene would mean I could have different render settings and any changes to camera, animation etc would be reflected in both scenes (in case I need to re-render or set up another shot).
My understanding is I need an alpha for the background and a solid colour (black) for the objects that are masking. How do I set that up?
What render settings and renderer? I guess it doesn't matter, but what is fastest most efficient?

